# Create folder in user mailbox with Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

want to use the Graph API to create a folder in a user's mailbox that exists in Exchange Online.
As a result of the investigation, if I use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/testuser01@domain.com/mailFolders", I feel that it is possible, but an error is displayed and I cannot create it.
Currently, "Exchange> Mail.ReadWrite, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite" is assigned to the execution user (admin).
However, it says "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again." Is the permission wrong?
Or is the specified URL incorrect?
Sorry to trouble you, but thank you for your response.

【Append】

```
$body = @{
    grant_type="client_credentials"
    resource=$resource
    client_id=$ClientID
    client_secret=$ClientSecret
}
`#Get Token
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$TenantName/oauth2/token -Body $body
```

[API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gig25.png)

Comment: Please show the screenshot of the `API permissions` of your app registration, and how did you get the access token and call the api?

Comment: Please also update the question with the way you used to get the token.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I updated it, but is it OK?

Comment: Please check my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I was able to execute normally with the contents you received.
I would like to know the command required to actually create a folder using the Graph API in PowerShell, should it be listed as another question?
I got the token with the previous method and created it with the following command.
However, no error was displayed with "StatusCode = 200", but the folder was not created.
I apologize for all the questions, but I would appreciate it if you could confirm.

Comment: $url = "$resource/v1.0/users/testuser01@domain.com/mailFolders/Archive?displayName='TestMailFolder'"
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headerParams -Uri $url

Comment: Could you get the mailFolders with this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: And from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body), the `displayName` should be included in the request body, but you put it in the request url. Also, I think you need to use `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Comment: I gave you a powershell sample to call the API to create a MailFolder, please check my update.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I was able to create it with the contents you taught me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token to call Microsoft Graph - [`Create MailFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), so you need to add the Application permission `Mail.ReadWrite` of Micrsoft Graph to your AD App.

1.Add the Application permission `Mail.ReadWrite` like below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

2.Click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button, and make sure the `$resource` in your request is `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

[image]

**Update:**

Here is a powershell sample to call [`Create MailFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API to create MailFolder.

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/joyw@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders"
$headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer <access-token-here>'
}
$body = ConvertTo-Json @{
    "displayName" = "testfolder1"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

[image]

Check the result in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) with [`List mailFolders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

[image]